# Генерация CSS кода

Tags: css

Недавно увидел сайт, у которого внутри одного файла стилей ~7000 строк `CSS` кода.
Та вот, вопрос: весь этот код пишется вручную или чем-то сгенерирован?

Comment: Существует множество инструментов для генерации стилей. Если интересен конкретный сайт, то Вы можете скопировать имя класса или идентификатор и погуглить. Имена файлов стилей иногда также могут сообщить чем они сгенерированы.

Comment: Ну семь тыщ строк не так уж трудно написать и вручную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно, скорее всего этот код чем-либо сгенерирован, хотя ничто, конечно, не мешает его написать и вручную. Генерации бывают трех видов:

1. Конкатенация (объединение) множества файлов в один. Это тот случай, когда вы можете использовать множество сторонних библиотек и плагинов для своего сайта, которые содержат какие-то свои отдельные файлы, и вы хотите объединить их все в один файл, ради скорости работы сайта. Посмотрите на инструмент `Webpack`, к примеру. Одновременно с этой операцией также обычно делают минификацию кода, когда он максимально сжимается по размеру - убираются все лишние пробелы, переносы и тому подобное.
2. Генерация кода всяческими препроцессорами. Это когда вы пишете свой код на их языке, и их препроцессоры в последствии разворачивают его уже в `css`-код, понятный всем браузерам. Смотрите в сторону `LESS`, `SASS`.
3. Генерация кода всяческими визуальными редакторами сайтов, как локально установленными, так и онлайн. Тогда вы вообще не дотрагиваетесь до кода, его генерирует робот. В первом случае можете посмотреть в сторону Adobe Muse, во втором в сторону [LPGenerator](http://lpgenerator.ru/?partner_id=dk66f9k82g), к примеру.